# Is there anyway to split curl request?

Tags: php, image, curl, upload

I'm currently make a PHP file to upload multi images to an image server upload. Which accepted multipart/form-data. Problem is they only accept maximium 10 images on each CURL request.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="IMG_00910"
Content-Type: image/png    ------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXX
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXX

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="IMG_00911"
Content-Type: image/png    ------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXX
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXX

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="IMG_00XXX"
Content-Type: image/png    ------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In an example, I'm uploading 20 requests as array like this:

```
$imgArr = array(
    'IMG_00900',
    'IMG_00901',
    'IMG_00902',
    'IMG_00903',
    'IMG_00904',
    'IMG_00905',
    'IMG_00906',
    'IMG_00907',
    'IMG_00XXX'
);
$startUpload = upload($imgArr);
$prin_r($ret);
//{"status":"true","data":["https://example.com/uploaded/IMG_00910","https://example.com/uploaded/IMG_00911","https://example.com/uploaded/IMG_00912","https://example.com/uploaded/IMG_00XX"]}
```

Everything OK if the request contains smaller than 10 IMGs request, so if I'm upload 100 IMGs, how can I split CURL 10 requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all images in one array (no matter how many):

```
$imgArr = array(
    'IMG_00900',
    'IMG_00901',
    'IMG_00902',
    'IMG_00903',
    'IMG_00904',
    'IMG_00905',
    'IMG_00906',
    'IMG_00907',
    'IMG_00XXX',
    ...
);
```

Then we can use [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split the array into into chunks with max 10 elements each.

Now we only need to iterate through the chunks and send them one chunk at the time.

```
foreach (array_chunk($imgArr, 10) as $imgSet) {
    $response = upload($imgSet);
    // Do something with the response, if you need to
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've learned a lot from you.